# Use accented character in mongo through command line

Tags: mongodb, command-line

I'm trying to get mongo to store a latin character

> ó

into a document, but somehow I can not seem to get pass the command line utility.

I'm using

> db.mycollection.update({"_id": "someawesomeid"} , {$set: { "metadata" : [ { "name" : "String with special ó character" }]}})

An it breaks with

> Thu Nov 28 04:53:16 malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset 105

How should I escape this?

Comment: As far as I remember this issue has been fixed. What version are you using. In my case in 2.4.6 it is working properly.

Comment: I have 2.0.4. Sadly I cant just upgrade it since this is the production environment, it has to be thoughtfully planed